# Only office version changed issue

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, ubuntu, onlyoffice

I have download 3.0 source code and run it `ubuntu` server.
When I upload existing file or open demo.docx, it renders it and enter to edit mode successfully.

If I modify the docx such as entering some words and closed the web browser after that once gain I open the browser and link to that docx file.
But it shows `"Version changed"` error message.
and I can't edit the docx file any more and I have lost the updated changes of file.

Even though I reload it several times, and tried other files, the prog shows the same error.

Please refer screenshot for error message:

[image]

Please suggest for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that every time you edit and save the document you should generate a new document key. Otherwise the Document Editing Service cannot open the file with the same key.

[Here](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/config/document#key) you can find some additional information about using the "document key" parameter.

Comment: thanks 'ibnpetr' for valueable replay, but I have ubuntu server on which I have installed onlyoffice. Could you tell me how to generate new key every time. - thanks once again.

Comment: Here are some examples:

Comment: [nodejs] (https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-integration/blob/master/web/documentserver-example/nodejs/helpers/docManager.js#L285) [csharp] (https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-integration/blob/master/web/documentserver-example/nodejs/helpers/docManager.js#L285) and how it is generated in the [ONLYOFFICE Community Server] (https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/CommunityServer/blob/master/web/studio/ASC.Web.Studio/Products/Files/Services/DocumentService/DocumentServiceHelper.cs#L182)